# display the 3D graphics in side the camera view?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, android-camera

I have finished my first opengl App. it's just a very simple thing.

But now, I just want to know how to display these shapes in side the camera "while the camera

is turned on"?

Any suggestions or tutorials?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a [CameraPreview](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html) surface and overlay your other stuff on it. There are a lot of tutorials on the web about doing that.